# Proof of expression by induction

Tags: induction

Hello I am trying to solve that the following expression is true for all positive integers n:

$$(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n) = 2^n \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot(2n-1).$$

I know that this question needs to be proven by inductions. Please give me hint.

Comment: Since you've identified induction as the proof method, you need a base case and an inductive step to do that. For the positive integers, what is the base case? Can you formulate how the inductive step should look? Inductive steps always assume that the relationship is true for $n$ and then seek to show that it is then also true for $n+1$.

Comment: The base case is $n=1$, but in that case the equation becomes $1\cdot 2=2^1\cdot 1$; there is no $3$ or $5$ in it.

Comment: And how should I get the 3 and the 5? Using more terms of n+1, n+2, n+3?, because then a 4 would appear.

Comment: @user92821 Once you've shown that the statement is true for $n=1$ then you need to do the inductive step, as manthanomen suggests. The 3,5,etc. will appear naturally there.

Comment: So would we get the base case from 2n-2=0 for both LHS and RHS?

Answer (score 1):

To prove a statement using induction, you need to do two things. First, prove the statement for the smallest applicable value of $n$ (called the *base case*). In your case, this is $n = 1$ since the statement involves only positive integers. Next, prove that if the statement is true for an arbitrary value of $n$, then it's true for $n + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT for the induction step:

$$\frac{(n+2)(n+3)\ldots(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(2n)}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}=2(2n+1)\;;$$

what is

$$\frac{2^{n+1}\cdot1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n+1)}{2^n\cdot1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}\;?$$

Comment: Oh that would be 2(2n+1)!

Comment: @user92821: It would indeed (assuming that your exclamation point is punctuation and not a factorial sign).

Comment: haha yes, thanks so much!

Comment: So would we get the base case from 2n-2=0 for both LHS and RHS?

Comment: @user92821: For the base case just substitute $n=1$ into the original expression and check that the two sides are equal: on the left there is just $2$, since $n+1=2n$ when $n=1$, and on the right you have $2^1\cdot1$, which is also $2$. // You’re welcome!